# How do I debug Verilog code where simulation functions as intended, but implementation doesn't?

Tags: debugging, verilog, fpga

I'm a bit stumped.

I have a fairly large verilog module that I've tested in Simulation (iSim) and it functions as I want. Now I've hooked up it up in real life to another device using SPI, and some stuff works, and some stuff doesn't.

For example,

I can send a value using command A, and verify that the right value was received using command B. Works no problem.

But if I send a value using command C, I cannot verify that it was received using command D. In simulation it works fine, so I feel I can't really gain anything from simulating any more.

I have looked at the signals on a logic analyzer, and the controller device (not my design) sends the right messages. When I issue command B, I can see the return values correct from my device (I know SPI works anyways). I don't know whether C or D work correctly. D just returns 0s, so maybe C didn't work in the first place. There is no way to step through Verilog, and this module is packaged as IP for Vivado.

Here are two screenshots. First is simulation (I send 5, then 2, then I expect it to return 4 on the next send, which it does; followed by zeros). 
[image]

Here is what I get in reality (the first two bytes don't matter, 5 is a left over from previously sent value):
[image]

Here is a command (B) that works in returning a correct value (it responds to the 0x01 being sent):
[image]

Does anyone have any advice for debugging this? I have literally no idea how to proceed.
I can't really reproduce this behaviour in simulation.

Comment: do you synthesise the RTL to get a gates file. you should be able to simulate the gates and get equivalent results. RTL to gates mismatch is normally due to not following RTL best practices. Could you create a minimal example which shows the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are synthesizing to an FPGA, you have a few more options on how to debug your synthesized, on-chip design. As you are using Vivado, you can use ChipScope to look at any signal in your system; allowing you to view a waveform of that signal over time just as you would in simulation (though more restricted). By including the ChipScope IPs into your synthesis, you can sent waveform data back to the Vivaod software which will display a waveform of your selected signals to help you see whats going on inside the FPGA as the system runs. (Note, if you were using Altera's stuff, you can use their equivalent called SignalTap; its pretty much the same thing)

There are numerous tutorial online on how to incorporate and run ChipScope, heres one from the Xilinx website:
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2012_4/ug936-vivado-tutorial-programming-debugging.pdf
Many other use ISE, but the steps are very similar as both typically involve using the coregen tool (though I think you can also add ChipScope via synthesis flow, so there are multiple options on how to incorporate it into your design).

Once on the FPGA, you have access to what is effectively an internal logic analyzer. Note that it does take up some LEs on the FPGA and can take up a fair amount of block RAM depending on how many samples you want to take out your signals.

Tim's answer provides a good description of how to deal with on-chip debugging if you are designing purely for ASIC; so see his answer if you want more information about standard, non-FPGA debugging solutions.

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to get ChipScope to do anything, but it's proving to be difficult (as in, a 'difficult' child). I don't understand why, but it does not let me view all signals. For example, I can only view bits 5 and 7 of my control register. Secondly, the integration with the Xilinx SDK (ARM code) is painful. I'm currently fighting it over setting breakpoints in the C++ code, and of course it doesn't want to. It also doesn't seem to execute the C++ code, just sitting at some random point in the disassembler forever.

Comment: Interesting; unfortunately, its been a while since Ive done anything with ChipScope and dont have access to an FPGA I might help you on. Its the right tool, but it can be a bit annoying to work with. Best of luck though!

Answer (score 3):

In cases like this you might want to think about adding additional logic which is used just for debugging. ('Design for debug') is a common term used for thinking about this kind of logic.

So you have one chip interface (SPI), which you don't know if it works correctly. Since it seems not to be working, you can't trust debugging over this interface, because if you get an odd result you can't determine what it means.

Since you're working on an FPGA, are there any other interfaces other than SPI which you can get working correctly? Maybe 7-segment display, LEDs, JTAG, VGA, etc?

Try to think of other creative ways to get data out of your chip that don't require the SPI interface.

- If you have 4 LEDs, A through D, can you light up each LED for 1 second each time a command of that type is received?
- Can you have a 7-seg display the current state of your SPI receiver's state machine, or have it indicate certain error codes if some unknown command is received?
- Can you draw over VGA to a monitor a binary sequence of the incoming SPI bitstream?

Once you can start narrowing down with data what is actually happening inside your hardware, you can narrowing the problem space to go inspect for possible problems.

Comment: Little cool thing since hes using Vivado: he can use ChipScope modules to directly view internal singals. ChipScope is Xilinx's FPGA debugging tool which will act as a logic analyzer and send waveform data directly to the Vivado software, letting him debug on chip without having to implement a new interface which may have bugs of its own. If going to ASIC, having JTAG or something is really ideal, but for FPGA work, ChipScope is pretty good. (SignalTap on Altera boards)

Comment: Tim, thanks. I know that the SPI interface works on its own, it's the internal workings that are apparently not working same as in simulation. I use the 8 LEDs on my board to display the RX data. I also checked that command C (write) works, but I don't think it ever gets transferred between registers, which is pretty weird. But in any case command D returns 0s because the desired register is actually 0. I'll try to wire some other state signals out. I have a VGA interface, but I don't have the character printing interface implemented.

Comment: @Unn, ChipScope is a separate debugging tool right? I'm just using a USB cable right now. Going to go see if I can find a ChipScope in the lab.

Comment: @Mewa No, ChipScope isnt actually a hard logic analyzer (though having one of those or at least an oscilloscope isnt a terrible thing to have access to). Its a synthesizable IP, like most Xilinx IPs, that you can have instantiated in your design (or incorporate it during synthesis). If you look online, you can find a bunch of tutorials on how to integrate it into your design. Once setup and put on the chip, it will communicate buffered waveform data back to Vivado via your USB serial connection.

Comment: @Unn, fantastic, I'll give this a shot. This design is driving me mad :) I have a logic analyzer that I already use, but this should be way more helpful.

Comment: @Unn You could probably expand your comments into separate answer about ChipScope, since it's pretty useful and pretty different from what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why code that runs ok in RTL simulation behaves differently in the FPGA. It is important to consider all possibilities. Chipscope suggested above is definitely a step in right direction and it could give you hint, where to look further. These reasons could be:

- The FPGA implementation flow was not executed properly. Did you have right timing constraints, were they met during implementation, especially P&R phase, pin placements, I/O properties, right clock properties. Usually you can find hints inspecting FPGA implementation reports. This is a tedious part, but needed sometimes. Incorrect implementation flow can also result in FPGA implementations that work or don't depending on the run or small unrelated changes (seen this problem many times!).
- RTL/netlist discrepancies, e.g. due to incorrect usage `ifdef within design or during synthesis phase, selecting incorrect file for synthesis or the same verily module defined in multiple places. Often, the hint could be found by inspecting removed flop list or synthesis warnings.
- Discrepancy between RTL simulation and board environment. They could be external like the clock/data alignment on the interface, but also internal: improper CDC, not handling clock or reset tree delays properly. Note, that X-propagation and CDC is not handled properly in RTL, unless you code in a certain way. Problems with those could be often only seen in netlist simulation environment.
- Lastly, the FPGA board problems, like faulty clock source or power supply, heat can also be at fault. They worth checking, but I'd leave those as a last resource. Some folks have a dedicated board/FPGA test design proven to work on the good board that would catch some of those problems.

As a final note, the biggest return is given by investing in simulation environment. Some folks think that since FPGA can be debugged with chipscope and reprogrammed quickly, there is no need in good simulation environment. It probably depends on the size of the project, but my experience is that for most of modern FPGA projects the good simulation environment saves a lot of time spent in the lab looking through chipscope and logic analyzers captures.